# Python Excel, Is it possible to update values of a created graph?

Tags: python, graph, openpyxl

I made a sheet with a graph using `python` and `openpyxl`.    Later on in the code I add some extra cells that I would also like to see in the graph.   Is there a way that I can change the range of cell that the graph is using, or maybe there is another library that lets me do this?

**Example:**
my graph initially uses columns A1:B10, then I want to update it to use A1:D10

Currently I am deleting the sheet, and recreating it, writing back the values and making the graph again,  the problem is that this is a big process that takes days, and there will be a point that rewriting the sheet will take some time.

Comment: I'm not sure if it works with `openpyxl`, but with Excel VBA I often create charts which are linked to ranges which are larger than the range which contains the values. Most Excel chart types ignore blanks. Later on, when the code calculates new values I push the values to the spreadsheet and the chart updates automatically. I think of these charts as monitors for given ranges and once they are set up I just worry about the ranges. Perhaps you can set up the chart to monitor all of A1:D10

Comment: thanks,   yes  adding extra cells works,  the graphs looks funny since it only shows the cells with values, but the empty cells  still take space in the graph. ( I will manually click in the graph and filter those),   that make me wonder if we can auto filter the graphs  but I think that might be another question outside this post.

Comment: Below link might help with the alternative solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020766/graphs-lost-while-overwriting-to-existing-excel-file-in-python/42971540#42971540

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is not possible to preserve charts in existing files. With rewrite in version 2.3 of openpyxl the groundwork has been laid that will make this possible. When it happens will depend on the resources available to do the work. Pull requests gladly accepted.

In the meantime you might be able find a workaround by writing macros to create the charts for you because macros are preserved. A bit clumsy but should work.

Make sure that you are using version 2.3 or higher when working on charts as the API has changed slightly.