# using openpyxl to change an excel document without removing existing data and graphs

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to use python to copy data from a dat file to an excel template with openpyxl. I tried doing a few tests to play with a template and found that when I saved the file it deleted most of the existing cells and all of the graphs. I read in another question that openpyxl might not be good for editing existing spreadsheets. Is there a better option or a way to get this one to work?

This is the code I was working on just to see if I could edit the spreadsheet:

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsm', keep_vba=True)
A=wb.get_sheet_by_name("A")
g=A['F24'].value
print g
A['A1'].value=g
print A['A1'].value
wb.save('file2.xlsm')
```

When I opened file2 most of the formatting, data, and all the graphs were gone.

Edit:So I'm trying out xlwings and I can't find a good tutorial or list of terms used. Anyone know where I can find that?

Comment: Have you looked at xlwings?  http://xlwings.org

Comment: I saw it but I can't find much about its library. I downloaded it and my first attempt at using it worked fine until I tried to close it and it corrupted the file I was working on. I'll play with it some more to see if it suits my needs.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I found out what happened. I thought it closed but it didn't so when I tried to open it again it said it was corrupted or didn't exist. A few hours later after my comment I made a trip to task manager to force close it and all was fine.

Comment: Below link might help you with alternative solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020766/graphs-lost-while-overwriting-to-existing-excel-file-in-python/42971540#42971540

Answer (score 1):

This is possible starting with version 2.5 of openpyxl.

Comment: Is there any example which I can use to preserve the charts. For pivots, we can use below to refresh the pivot. sheet = workbook["Pivot"]
pivot = sheet._pivots[0]
pivot.cache.refreshOnLoad = True'''